# Complexity of checking whether the vertex has more neighbors of blue or red color

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs

Assume we have a set of $s$ vertices, say $\{w_1,\ldots,w_s\}$. Assume every vertex $w_i$ has at most $q$ neighbours coloured either red or blue, for some positive integer $q\ge 1$. I would like to check how many neighbours of each colour $w_i$ for each $i\in \{1,\ldots,s\}$ has. What is the complexity of doing it?

Since every $w_i$ for each $i\in \{1,\ldots,s\}$ has at most $q$ neighbours to check and we have to check $s$ neighbours does that mean that the complexity is $O(q*s)$?

Comment: $O(qs)$ is definitely enough, but you can do it in time $O(m+s)$ where $m$ is the number of edges of the graph. Keep a counter $r_i$ for each vertex $w_i$. This counter will be the number of red neighbors of $w_i$ and is initialized to $0$. Then, for each edge $(w_i,w_j)$ of the graph do the following: 1) if $w_i$ is red, add $1$ to $c_j$, 2) if $w_j$ is red, add $1$ to $c_i$.
At the end of this procedure, $w_i$ has exactly $r_i$ red neighbors and $\delta_i - r_i$ blue neighbors, where $\delta_i$ is the degree of $w_i$. Notice that $O(m+s)$ is never asymptotically worse than $O(qs)$.

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense!

Comment: (re-check the title of your question: I don't expect a vertex to have vertices at all.)

Comment: Thanks I fixed it